# How to make squid proxy to allow all connections from different IPs

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, squid, proxy-server

I setup squid proxy on my VPS on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). But I have a problem - my home IP address changes constantly, since it is dynamic. I tried to use [no-ip](http://www.noip.com) (since it's free) but when I add `acl myhome srcdomain mydomain.no-ip.org`, I cannot connect to the proxy.

I also tried to add a dot in mydomain.no-ip.org, but still no luck. So I decided to open it to all, so no matter what my home IP is, still, I can't connect to squid.

How can I allow squid to accept all incoming connections, regardless of the originating IP address?  Or do is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also use this after you defined the ACL:

```
http_access allow myhome
```

Another suggestion if you cant get the no-ip to work, is perhaps defining an entire range of IP's. If you track your IP changes you should be able to work out a list of addresses. In my case I usually I only get a few addresses and they are all in the same networks.

Eg. I will get something like: 192.168.1.25 and then only the last 1 or 2 numbers change. So you could simply allow all IP's from 192.168.0.0. Not the nicest solution, I think your no-ip solution is much better if u can get that to work.

EDIT: Some info on how to enable more debug info to work out why you cant get access, In squid.conf enable debugging for section 33 at level 2. For example:

```
debug_options ALL,1 33,2
```

Restart squid then try and use your proxy, when it fails to work check the  cache.log for the error. That should hopefully tell you why its not working.

Also just as a test to make sure your no-ip domain is working correctly as sometimes it takes a while for DNS to catch up, use:

```
nslookup no-ip-host-name
```

That should return your IP address, check to make sure that is actually your IP. If they dont match its because the DNS servers configured are a bit slow to update. I found OpenDNS is pretty quick for updates. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: actually, i already allow it. but i cannot connect when using no-ip. but, when i use `acl myhome src my-public-ip-here` instead of `acl myhome srcdomain no-ip-domain-here` i can connect to the internet. so what i did, i allow all. but i don't know if this is a good idea since anyone can use this when they know the ip of my squid server

Comment: yea that makes your proxy a public one, u will have people using that very soon. People use port scanners to find them. So best to fix it. I've added more info to my answer for you. Hope that helps.